alaligne not working in Gregorian Chant musixgre library
It is needed to code the "Pater noster" Gregorian Chant using Musixtex with musixgre library, but alaligne command is not working. The basic code is as follow:
\documentclass[%
latin,spanish,
border={2pt 7pt 250pt -7pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{scalerel}%Escalar símbolos
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\input musixlit
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\paperwidth%
%\hsize=\linewidth%
%\scale{0.7}%
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Letras}{{Pa-ter} {nos-ter}, {qui es in} {c{\ae}-lis}; {sanc-} {ti-fi-} {cé-tur} no-men {tu-um}; ad-{vé-ni-at} {rég-num} {tu-um;} {fi-at} {vo-lún-tas} {tu-a}, {si-cut in} {c{\ae}-lo} {et in} {ter-ra;} {Pa-nem} {nos-trum} {quo-ti-} {di-á-num} {da no- bis} {hó-di}-e; {et di}-{mít-te} {no-bis} {dé-bi-ta} nos-{tra,} {si-cut} {et nos} {di-mít}-{ti-mus} {de-bi}-{tó-ri}-bus {nos-tris;} et ne nos in-dú-cas in ten-ta-ti-ón-em. Sed lí-be-ra nos a ma-lo. Am-en.}%
\setsongraise{1}{0.15cm}
\font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
%\parindent0mm
%\sepbarrules
\instrumentnumber{1}
\nobarnumbers
\setlines14
\setclef1{3000}
\setstaffs11
\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianCclef
\startpiece
\A\assignlyrics{1}{Letras}%
%\addspace{-3\afterruleskip}
\notes\bistropha{a}{b} \bistropha{c}{c} \tristropha{c}{c}{c} \bistropha{c}{b} \squ{c} \bistropha{c}{c} \bistropha{c}{c} \squ{b}\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\alaligne%
\notes\squ{a} \bistropha{c}{c} \squ{a} \tristropha{b}{c}{c} \bistropha{c}{c} \bistropha{c}{b} \bistropha{a}{b} \tristropha{c}{c}{c}\en%
\alaligne%
\notes\bistropha{c}{c} \tristropha{c}{c}{c} \bistropha{c}{c} \bistropha{b}{a} \bistropha{c}{c} \bistropha{a}{b} \bistropha{c}{c} \bistropha{c}{c}\en%
\alaligne%
\notes\tristropha{c}{c}{c}\tristropha{c}{c}{c}\bistropha{c}{c}\squ{b}\bistropha{a}{a}\bistropha{b}{b}\bistropha{c}{c}\tristropha{c}{c}{c}\squ{c}\en%
\alaligne%
\notes\squ{c}\bistropha{c}{c}\bistropha{c}{c}\bistropha{c}{c}\bistropha{c}{c}\bistropha{c}{c}\bistropha{c}{b}\squ{a}\bistropha{c}{c}\squ{a}\squ{a}\en%
%\alaligne%
%\notes\squ{a}\bistropha{b}{b}\bistropha{c}{c}\bistropha{c}{c}\bistropha{c}{c}\squ{a}\bar\bistropha{c}{c}\bistropha{c}{c}\bistropha{c}{c}\squ{c}\squ{a}\en%
\endpiece%
%\nolyr%
%\lyricsoff%
\end{music}
\end{document}

Notice that after the four system staff, the alaligne is not working properly.
The current output is as follow:

Teh desired output is as follow:


I do not know what you are doing. When I don't musixflx I have the notes in the lines, when I do, I get overfull hboxes. Is this ´\node (B) [above right = 0.105cm and -1.093cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\scaleobj{1.85}{\lilyGlyph{hyphen}}´ meant to be a \ust? Please delete all unwanted spaces inside your music code and verify if you haven't forgotten to put % at the end of a line. With your code now it takes too much time to help you. Besides, some times it helps to delete all auxiliary files and start compiling again.

I had deleted the tikzpicture environment, still the alaligne is not working...


Don't put spaces inside music, because this may cause unwanted errors / glue! You still have too many in your code.
Your problem seems to be caused by \hsize=\paperwidth%.
With \hsize=\linewidth% I don't have the problem.
The amssymb package offers a medium and short bar. This is better than using Tikz in music.

My code would be:
\documentclass[%
latin,spanish,
border={2pt 7pt 2pt -7pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}%
\usepackage{musicography}%
\usepackage{scalerel}%Escalar símbolos
\usepackage{musixtex}%
\input musixlyr%
\input musixlit%
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amssymb}% %$\shortmid$ and $\mid$
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}%
\usepackage{fontawesome5}%
\usepackage{fontspec}%
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}%
%
\begin{document}%
\begin{music}%
\hsize=\linewidth% not: \pagewidth
\nostartrule% you omitted this!
%\hsize=\linewidth%
%\scale{0.7}%
\resetlyrics%
\setlyrics{Letras}{Pa-ter nos-ter, qui es in c{\ae}-lis; sanc-ti-fi-cé-tur no-men tu-um; ad-vé-ni-at rég-num tu-um; fi-at vo-lún-tas tu-a, si-cut in c{\ae}-lo et in ter-ra; Pa-nem nos-trum quo-ti-di-án-um da no-bis hó-di-e; et di-mít-te no-bis dé-bi-ta nos-tra, si-cut et nos di-mít-ti-mus de-bi-tó-ri-bus nos-tris; et ne nos in-dú-cas in ten-ta-ti-ón-em. Sed lí-be-ra nos a ma-lo. Am-en.}%
\setsongraise{1}{0.15cm}%
\font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
%\parindent0mm
%\sepbarrules
\instrumentnumber{1}%
\nobarnumbers%
\setlines14%
\setclef1{3000}%
\setstaffs11%
\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianCclef%
%
%
\newcommand{\ustt}[1]{\raisebox{0.2\Interligne}{\kern-1.4pt \ust {#1}\kern1.4pt}}% normal size \ust centered and put higher for notes on a line
%
\newcommand{\usttt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\medtype \raisebox{0.1\Interligne}-}}% shorter \ust
%
\newcommand{\ptt}[1]{\kern-3pt\pt {#1}\kern3pt}% point closer to note head (original distance is defined for larger \nq)
%
%\newcommand{\caeg}{\zcharnote{5}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%Barra Vertical
%\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.295) -- ++(0,0.15); %
%\end{tikzpicture}}}% works, but quite complicated if there is an existing symbol in amssymb
%
\newcommand{\caeg}{\charnote d{$\shortmid$\hbsk}}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbr}{\notes\zcharnote O{$\mid$}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbre}{\zcharnote O{\kern-1.6pt$\mid$}}% see differences in spacing
%
\startpiece%
\A\assignlyrics{1}{Letras}%
\addspace{0.5\afterruleskip}%
\notes\squ{a}\squ{b}\squ{c}\squ{c}\squ{c}\squ{c}\squ{c}\squ{c}\ptt b\squ{b}\caeg%
\squ{c}\squ{c}\squ{c}\squ{c}\squ{c}\squ{b}\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\zalaligne% there is no \alaligne, it is a custos, for which I haven't found a symbol yet (half a \squ mirrored, with stem up)
%
\notes\squ{ac}\ptt c\squ{c}\enotes\sbr%
\notes\squ{ab}\squ{c}\squ{c}\squ{cc}\squ{c}\ptt b\squ{b}%
\caeg\squ{a}\squ{b}\squ{c}\squ{c}\squ{c}\en%
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{c}\usttt c\squ c%
\caeg%
\ustt c\squ{c}\ustt b\squ{c}\ust c\squ{cc}\squ{cba}\pt c\squ{c}\ptt c\squ{c}\charnote O{$\mid$}\hbsk%
\squ{a}\squ{b}\squ{c}\sbre\en%
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{cc}\squ{c}\squ{c}\squ{c}\squ{c}\squ{c}\squ{c}\squ{c}\squ{c}\squ{c}\squ{b}\caeg\hbsk% 
\squ{aa}\squ{b}\squ{b}\squ{c}\sbre\en%
\zstoppiece
%\nolyr%
%\lyricsoff%
\end{music}
\end{document}

Compiled with LuaLaTeX (and musixflx) I get this:

You can adapt the definitions like you want.

\newcommand{\btt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf{\kern1.2pt \raisebox{-0.9\Interligne}{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}\kern-1.2pt}}}% vertical bar below center of note head (original distance)
